# Set state and then reading the state shows the previous value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code that maintains the value when the textbox value is changed.  However, whilst debugging the valueHasChangedEvent the variable x line shown below holds the previous value strangely.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?  The example shown is when I enter 'test123' into the textbox.

Thanks

**onChange event**

```
<Input onChange={this.valueHasChangedEvent}
   type="text" 
   name="test" 
   id="test" />
```

**Method**

```
valueHasChangedEvent = (event) => {
    var self = this;
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    self.setState({test: value});  // value = 'test123'

    var x = self.state.test;  // x = 'test12'
}
```

Comment: It’s definitely that duplicate @MoshFeu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State needs some time to change, and since you are reading the state value before the state mutates, you get the previous value as output. So you need to write it in the callback to the setState function or read it in shouldComponentUpdate()

```
var x;
self.setState({test: value}, (x) => {
  x = self.state.test
});
```

Comment: Please refer the OP to an existing answer instead of answering again.. Thanks